# rip (transcode) multiple titles, from a tv series dvd, automatically

Tags: video, dvd, tv, disk-ripping

I want to rip some tv series. dvd::rip doesnt allow me to transcode all the titles with one click, which means doing the same process many times (20~ eps x many seasons= many videos).

Is there any software or script you know to copy all the dvds to my hd and then transcode them all to xvid files?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handbrake and DVD::RIP will both let you queue things but it's quite a tedious process. You have to manually input the episode number, amongst other tedious things. It wasn't for me.

So when I wanted to rip my Family Guy DVDs, I wrote a simple script that I could reuse in the future:

```
#!/bin/bash

series=$1
disk=$2
count=$3
offset=0
name="Family Guy"
scratch="~/Desktop/"
destination="/media/ned/tv/$name"

#mkdir $scratch

for c in $(seq 1 1 $count)
do
    ep=`printf "%02.f" $(( ($disk-1)*$count+$c ))`
    fn="$scratch/$name ${series}x$ep.mp4"
    echo "Ripping $name ${series}x${ep} to fn"
    /home/oli/hb/HandBrakeCLI -S 200 -Z Television -a 1 -i /dev/sr0 -o "$fn" -t $(($c + $offset))
done

#echo "moving..."
#mv $scratch/* "$destination"
echo "done."

eject
sleep 2
eject
```

This is really very raw and there's plenty of scope for improving it. The format for calling it is:

```
script_name <series> <disk> <number-of-episodes-per-disk>
```

Comment: the script is nice. handbrake also looks very good. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

there is some dvd::rip queue project, in software-center it states that

> dvdrip-queue lets you queue up dvd::rip projects to be encoded, so you don't have to babysit when you're ripping a bunch of dvd's or if you're ripping a dvd with several titles on it (like a tv show)

i will update this when i will try it