# How to mostly automate authoring video dvds?

Tags: video, dvd

How to take a few hundred video files of various formats and put them on dvds, with a dvd menu item for each video file?

Automated to the extend that doing any action for each and every file is too time consuming to be feasible.

edit: I'm going to look at automating with handbrake per https://askubuntu.com/a/39156/174758

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to check out [dvdauthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/), which takes a xml file as input for a menu. I don't know if you know any scripting, but since it's a command line tool, this could be programmed as a simple loop.

An example script of making automating this process is [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111506). It makes use of both dvdauthor and ffmpeg to convert the file to dvd.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer and expand this a bit so it's of use to the OP?  Then drop me a note @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote instead of downvoting...

Comment: After quick look on man page of it, it support 2 ways : xml project file or command arguments.